# AnyLogic: is it possible to embed code to define a color?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

In the Java source code of my class, I saw that color is integrated as a method call with the input color as a word. So it seems that you can't implement any code, because color is defined with `shape.setFillColor()`.
Is there a way around this? Otherwise a more complicated coloring would not be possible.
I have attached an example here in this screenshot how I could imagine it, however I get some errors because semicolons are missing and I have not declared the variables. So my problem is that i don't know how and if i can query if-else as well as embed switch case. So how can I write various functions for a color setting?
Can someone help me?
Example code for a color change of a rectangle

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a function that returns Color type, e.g. `chooseColor(<your parameters>)` and you could call `shape.setFillColor(chooseColor(<your parameters>))`. The body of the `chooseColor()` function can be based on the example code you posted.

Or you could call the `chooseColor()` function directly at the Fill color property of your shape if it is not too computation heavy, otherwise it could slow down the simulation.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you need, tbh. You can make coloring as complex as you like. But once you decide on a color, you must call `shape.setFillColor(theColorYouChose)` to actually do it...

You can, however, create any possible color using `Color myNewColor = new Color(x,y,z,a)` where x, y and z are RGB values (0-255) and the last is the transparency you want (also 0-255)

To use this with switch/if statements, you can create a local `Color` variable and use it at the end for the shape:

```
Color myColor = new Color(0,0,0,0);
switch(someThing) {
    case myCase:
        myColor = yellowGreen;
        break;
    case myOtherCase:
        if (someCondition) {
            myColor = new Color(12, 222,45,122);
        } else {
            myColor = blue;
        }
        break;
    }
shape.setFillColor(myColor);
```

Comment: My problem is that i don't know how and if i can query if-else as well as embed switch case. So how can I write various functions for a color setting? As you said right, in `shape.setFillColor()` comes only the color and not the whole code of for example a switch case. Here it comes to syntax problems, if I start to write semicolons and whole functions inside this method `shape.setFillColor()`.

Comment: Hi Benjamin, thanks again for your helpful answer! Last question, afterwards I will edit and precise my question: WHERE do I have to create these local variables? For sure not inside the `Fill color` code box, right? Where would you recommend me to put the code?

Comment: Where ever you need to set the color... Best open a new issue for that, tbh. This reply here is answering your original question. Keep your problems separate ;) See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks a lot, I edited my original question for better understanding. :)